# When an orbiting electron loses energy does it lose potential energy, kinetic energy or both?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy

When an electron orbiting an atomic nucleus is excited, does it  shortly after get closer to the nucleus and lose potential energy or does it lose kinetic energy too?

Comment: For one thing electrons are not objects, they don't have positions and velocities. 

The best way to think about it semi-classically is that the energy in an excited atom is in the quantized electromagnetic field. When the atom de-excites, the atom (which is the volume of space close to the nucleus that we chose to call "the atom") loses a photon worth of energy, momentum and angular momentum and the free electromagnetic field outside of the atom's volume gains a photon's worth of energy, momentum and angular momentum.

Comment: You tell us. Calculate $\langle \psi_0|\hat V|\psi_0\rangle$ and $\langle \psi_0|\hat T|\psi_0\rangle$. Then calculate $\langle \psi_1|\hat V|\psi_1\rangle$ and $\langle \psi_1|\hat T|\psi_1\rangle$. Then compare the values.

Comment: If you mean to consider a hydrogenic atom (you do not specify exactly what you mean) then you may find the following equalities helpful (via the Virial Theorem): $\langle \hat H\rangle = \langle \hat V \rangle/2 = -\langle \hat T\rangle$.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it shows ignorance of mainstream physics modeling of electrons atoms etc. see for hydrogen http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Chemical/eleorb.html